# How to set up the create android device options

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, virtual-device-manager

In Eclipse, with Android Device Manager menu for setting emulation framework according to these procedure https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html, I get following error

[image]

I have config this way.

[image]

What should i use as CPU/ABI ? With Nexus 7, default is RAM 1024. Why is there the error message then ?

This is not working either

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is there because you are trying to emulate MORE than 768MB of RAM, so you might want to set it to 768 or 512. Also the CPU looks good.

Comment: even with 512 cannot launch; click on OK, nothing happens and OK is immediately clickable again.thanks

Comment: That's strange. I configured an AVD the same way you did and it works. Did you try to start the AVD as administrator?

Comment: You also find the AVD Manager as an *.exe file in your Android SDK directory in the sdk folder(.../AndroidSDK/sdk/AVD Manager.exe). And then just right click on it and run it as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error it is a warning.  Windows is not friendly with allocating ram to the emulator.  If it crashes and gives you a failed to allocate memory error the simplest solution is to just lower the amount of ram given to the emulator.

Comment: even with 512 cannot launch; click on OK, nothing happens and OK is immediately clickable again.thanks